# Llamar a arreglos dentro de un ciclo

Tags: javascript, array

Que tal me gustaria poder mandar a llamar a unos arreglos y recorrer cada uno de ellos en **Javascript** de manera dinamica.

Por ejemplo:

```
var idarray=[1,5,8]    
var arreglo1=[23,34,56,45,534]
var arreglo5=[34,34,12,65]
var arreglo8=[34.23.65.87]
```

Tengo "n" numero de arreglos que tienen el mismo nombre pero solo cambia el numero

> *arreglo* **1**

dichos numeros los tengo en otro array, entonces lo que quiero es mediante un ciclo mandar a llamar cada uno de los arreglos y recorrer sus elementos.

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Aquí tienes la solucion

```js
var idarray=[1,5,8];
var arreglo1=[23,34,56,45,534];
var arreglo5=[34,34,12,65];
var arreglo8=[34,23,65,87];

for(var i = 0; i < idarray.length; i++){
    var array = window["arreglo"+idarray[i]]; //llamo a la variable arreglo que tenga el numero del array idarray 
    console.log("arreglo"+idarray[i]);

    for(var j = 0; j < array.length; j++){ //recorro cada valor de dicho array
        console.log(array[j])
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Cris, saludos!!

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que recorrer el arreglo de los nombres de tus array y con ayuda de window mandarlos a llamar.

```
        <script>
  var idarray=[1,5]    
  var arreglo1=[23,34,56,45,534]
  var arreglo5=[34,34,12,65]

  for (x=0;x<idarray.length;x++){
    alert( window['arreglo' + idarray[x]]);
  }

  </script>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Ana, Saludos

Answer (score 0):

```js
var idarray=[1,5];    
var arreglo1=[23,34,56,45,534];
var arreglo5=[34,34,12,65];

for (i in idarray){
    var arrActual = window['arreglo' + idarray[i]];
    console.log("Arreglo "+ idarray[i]);
    for(x in arrActual){
      console.log("Valor " + arrActual[x] + " del array " + idarray[i]);
    }
}
```

Espero te sirva